# page can't view .doc file on the Ipad using asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have printer page which will get the binary file of .doc format and then print it

its working on IE,Firfox,chroom

but when i tried to view it on ipad it gave me empty page ??
below is  the code    :

```
                Dim filepath() As Byte
                filepath = Session(Request.QueryString("id"))
                Response.ClearHeaders()
                Response.ClearContent()
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=""MyFile.doc""")
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "myfiles")
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword")
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
                Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "public")
                Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate")
               Response.BinaryWrite(filepath)
                 Response.Flush()
                Response.End()
```

Comment: iPad does not know how to read word documents. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: i was able before to view it in ipad but the format was word document (.docx) but .doc its give empty page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the document in ms word and save it again 
in microsoft wrod format and then check

same code :

```
 Dim filepath() As Byte
            filepath = Session(Request.QueryString("id"))
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=""MyFile.doc""")
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "myfiles")
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword")
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
            Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "public")
            Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate")
           Response.BinaryWrite(filepath)
             Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
```